# How to fix an Image over an backgroundImage via css?

Tags: css

I have already put an Image as background image.Now I want to fix an another image over this background image in header, but whenever resolution get change the header Image position get disturbed I want to put in a fix position via css.Can anyone suugest me?

Comment: absolutely position your image using percents relative to your background image container

Comment: Give us an example of the css code you are using, and we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have misunderstood your question, but should it have any functions? Why not merge the image as one and use that as background?

Here is a video tutorial you can look at: youtube.com/watch?v=LNxfOrhNXgM Where it's used two images as background.

```
.clear{
content: ".";
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I have absoluteltly positioned my image relative to background image but still whenever I increase resoltion of screen then it gets disturbed (shift toward right) and when I use less resolution it shift towards left side.

Comment: Oki, I don't know how you are using positioning or sizes as there is no code to look at. Maybe you can use position: relative; or if its a problem related to how much empty space you have from each side you can make yourself a .clear class in css. I have made an example in the answer above.

Comment: or you could create two classes, just thinking framing the frame where each of them has independent background images.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I cannot merge it.because I am using one image from bottom and another one from top according to its design as background should have dark shade at lower side and whtie one on upper side on which I will place another image.